# Proptypes custom validators with Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a `Paginator` component whose props validation with Flow works like this:

```
type Props = {
  totalPages?: number,
  currentPage?: number,
  onClickPage?: Function
}
```

Now I would like to create a custom validator for the `currentPage`, specifically that it does needs to be equal or less than the `totalPages`.

With proptypes I would do this:

```
currentPage: (props, propName, component) => {
  if (currentPage > totalPages)
    return new Error(
      `{Invalid props ${propName} supplied to ${component}: ${propName} needs to be equal or less than totalPages.}`
    )
}
```

but how is this possible with Flow Type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to achieve this with flow typed, but it [looks like a good solution to this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L70-L74) is using flow typed together with [invariant](https://github.com/zertosh/invariant) or [warning](https://github.com/BerkeleyTrue/warning) and throwing in the `componentWillMount` method:

```
  componentWillMount = () => {
    warning(
      this.props.currentPage <= this.props.totalPages,
      'Your currentPage prop value is out of range'
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

See here - [flow.org/Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSsBYAQwBsYiBzCZAfgC4oA7AVwFsAjCOAGlygGNmcOBEbByVekzacefBIwDCJAJb8A1hIhSAYs0b9gKhdgC+2bIOGjxlCAwAUYRCgbwkyblGdIAckVZ7KGRgOBVGCi9+BFYwBRsGELCIgEp0AD4sPhUAMygnF2QAbR8wf0CAXShM0uQAOgJiMjtkFL48EWAhRiYIAHcoAFFhBDgHdrwoAANMAElGADdSFQATb0KoABJMUvKIU2DmMDBVCDWCLcxo2PixUwZt3YD93rPUC84oCABHZlIoUZQEjUd4ACyIPUapC09VMUwmbVMQA)

```
type Props = {
  totalPages?: number,
  currentPage?: number,
  onClickPage?: Function
}

currentPage: (props: Props, propName: string, component: string) => {
  if (props[propName] > props.totalPages)
    return new Error(
      `{Invalid props ${propName} supplied to ${component}: ${propName} needs to be equal or less than totalPages.}`
    )
}
```